# Reshaping a numpy vector

Tags: numpy, vector

I am really new to numpy. I have a numpy vector that when I run `y.shape` returns `(4000,)`. Is there a way, I can have it return `(4000, 1)`?

Comment: Use the `reshape` method.

Comment: @hpaulj can you give me an example? I have tried and can't get it to work

Comment: The function version, `np.reshape` has an example.  `reshape` does not work in-place; it returns a new array.

Comment: `y.reshape(-1,1)`?

Comment: i tried `y.reshape(4000, -1)` and i still get `(4000,)`

Answer (score 0):

```
np.reshape(y,(4000,1))
```

Reshape function can be used to do this

Comment: i get an error `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`